# Ошибка в PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, webkit

Вот что я пишу, и что выводит

```
phantomjs> phantomjs test.js // test.js находиться в папке с phantonjs.exe
Expected an identifier but found 'test' instead

phantomjs://repl-input:1 in global code
phantomjs>
```

В чем может быть проблем? Где я накосячил?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/30083194

Comment: @KostaB. Спасибо помогло!

Comment: [Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Нужно из командной строки запускать `phantomjs`:

```
$ phantomjs your-file.js
```

Положение когда вы на ходитесь в самом интерактивнов моде

```
phantomjs>
```

- **REPL mode** - ( read-eval-print loop) — цикл «чтение — вычисление — вывод»

[Почитать phantomjs REPL](http://phantomjs.org/repl.html)